How many minimum separators are created by removing an edge?
We write $G-e$ for the graph obtained from $G$ by deleting an edge $e$ in $G$. We denote by $\kappa(G)$ the vertex connectivity of $G$. We can easily prove the following result, and it may exist in some textbooks.
Theorem If $G$ has vertex  connectivty $k$, then  $k-1\le \kappa(G-e) \le  k$.
My question is how many $(k-1)$-separators can exist in $G-e$ at most.  When $k = 2$, we should be able to determine this. For some special cases, I am particularly concerned with the case when $k = 4$, especially when restricted to planar graphs.
Question 1: Let $G$ be a 4-connected  graph. What is the maximum number of 3-separators in $G-e$?
Question 2: Let $G$ be a 4-connected planar graph. What is the maximum number of 3-separators in $G-e$?

I've updated my answer to handle the general case.
For the case $k=2$, observe that if $G$ a cycle on $l+2$ vertices, then $G-e$ has $l$ $1$-separators. Similarly, for the case $k=1$, we can take a path.
We now show that for any $k, l\in \mathbb{N}$, there is a graph $G^k_l$ that is $k$-connected, and $G^k_l-e$ has at least $l$ $k$-separators. Start with a $(k-1)\times l$ grid, with vertices labelled $(i, j)$ where $i\in [k-1]$ and $j\in [l]$ in the natural way. Add all possible edges between vertices with a fixed $j$, for all $j\in [l]$. Finally, add a vertex called $(0,0)$ adjacent to $(i,1)$ for each $i$, and a vertex called $(0,l+1)$ adjacent to $(i, l)$, and add an edge between $(0,0)$ and $(l+1,0)$. Call this graph $G^k_l$. Below is a drawing of $G^4_6$.

Observe that $G^k_l$ is $k$-connected. Let $e$ denote the edge joining $(0,0)$ and $(0,l+1)$. In $G^k_l-e$, we have that for all $j\in [l]$, the set $\{(i,j): i\in [k-1]\}$ is a $(k-1)$-separator, so $G^k_l-e$ has at least $l$ $k-1$-separators (in fact it has more than $l$ such separators).

The above example can be modified slightly to be made planar in the case $k=4$ as follows: delete the edges of form $(1,j)(3,j)$, then subdivide the edges of form $(2,j)(2,j+1)$, and make the newly formed vertex adjacent to $(1,j), (3,j), (1,j+1), (3, j+1)$. See the below example.


It's not clear to me that $G_l$ itself is planar
